# What is the difference between the vector operator [] and at()

Tags: c++, pointers, types, stdvector, dereference

I'm messing around with a pointer to a vector of pointers

```
std::vector<int*>* MyVector;
```

Which I try to access using these 2 methods:

```
MyVector->at(i);    //This works
MyVector[i]         //This says "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type"
```

To my understanding, the difference between a vectors `[] operator` and `at` method is that the at method does additional boundary checks, so my question is why does the at method succeed in accessing the element whereas the `[] operator` does not?

**EDIT:**

Whole code here

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int*>* MyVector;

int main()
{
    MyVector = new std::vector<int*>;
    MyVector->push_back(new int(5));


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MyVector->size(); i++)
    {
        delete MyVector->at(i); //This works
        delete MyVector[i];     //This says "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MyVector` is a *pointer to a vector*, not a *vector*.

Two solutions:

1. Since `MyVector` is a pointer, you need to dereference the pointer
   first to get back the `vector`.

   ```
   (*MyVector)[i]
   ```
2. Less used: Use the `operator` keyword:

   ```
   MyVector->operator[](i)
   ```

Comment: Ah yes. Reading more carefully I see now that the at method returns a reference to the nth position of the vector where as the [] operator returns a reference to the nth position of the vectors container!

Comment: @Vishuu, `at` and `[]` do the exact same thing, but `at` additionally performs bounds checking and will throw an exception if you try to access memory out of bounds. That's the only difference

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've declared a pointer to a vector. In the second expression, you are effectively treating `MyVector` as an array in which you are trying to access the `i`th element of type `std::vector<int*>` (which I assume does not exist).