# Access Kaguya Lua state from a pointer

Tags: c++, lua

I need to have a class which is a child of class with a pointer to a Kaguya Lua state. In the child class i need to access values from the Lua state, which is done with a overloaded [] operator.

I have tried looking over the Kaguya source code in search for anwsers, but i have found nothing.

```
#include "kaguya.hpp"

class base
{
public:

    kaguya::State *state;

};

class derivate : public base
{
public:

    int foo()
    {
        return 2+5;
    }

    void exposeFunction()
    {
        state["foo"] = &foo;
    }

    derivate()
    {
        state = new kaguya::State;
    }
    ~derivate()
    {
        delete state;
    }

};

int main()
{
    derivate d;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the program to compile, but i get error "invalid types 'kaguya::State*[const char [4]]' for array subscript".

Comment: `state["foo"] = &foo;` -- This is illegal, regardless of what type of pointer `state` is.   Not knowing what `kayuga` is, maybe you should be dereferencing the pointer first, and then applying `[]` to the derferenced pointer?

Comment: Cant do that, because "'kaguya::State::State(const kaguya::State&)' is private within this context"

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645285/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vector-operator-and-at/53645399#53645399).   You need to get a `state` **object**, not a pointer..  To get the object, the pointer is dereferenced in some way shape or form.  The answer, even though it is for `std::vector`, applies to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `operator []` overload works on objects, not pointers.  Since `state` is a pointer you must either dereference the pointer first, and then use `operator []`:

```
(*state)["foo"]
```

or use the `operator` keyword on the pointer itself:

```
state->operator[]("foo")
```

or even more obtusely:

```
(*state).operator[]("foo")
```

or even a two-liner:

```
auto& temp = *state;
temp["foo"];
```